# Issues injecting Angular factories and services

Tags: angularjs

I don't know what it is about injecting factories, but I am having the most difficult time.

I've simulated what I'm attempting to do via this sample plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/I6MJRx?p=preview, which creates a kendo treelist - it works fine.

I have an `onChange` event in script.js which just writes to the console. That's also working.

My plunk loads the following:

1) Inits the `app` module, and creates the main controller `myCtrl` (script.js)

2) Injects `widgetLinkingFactory` int `myCtrl`

3) Injects `MyService` into `widgetLinkingFactory`

The order in which I load the files in `index.html` appears to be VERY important.

Again, the above plunk is NOT the real application. It demonstrates how I'm injecting factories and services.

My actual code is giving me grief. I'm having much trouble inject factories/services into other factories.

For example,

when debugging inside `function linking()` below, I can see neither 'CalculatorService' nor 'MyService' services. However, I can see the 'reportsContext' service.

```js
(function () {    
      
   // ******************************
   // Factory: 'widgetLinkingFactory'
   // ******************************
    'use strict';
    app.factory('widgetLinkingFactory', ['reportsContext', 'MyService', linking]);

    function linking(reportsContext, MyService) {
       
        var service = {
            linkCharts: linkCharts
        };
        return service;

        function linkCharts(parId, widgets, parentWidgetData) {         

     // *** WHEN DEBUGGING HERE, ***
            // I CANNOT SEE 'CalculatorService' AND 'MyService' 
     // HOWEVER I CAN SEE 'reportsContext' 
     
            if (parentWidgetData.parentObj === undefined) {
                // user clicked on root node of grid/treelist
            }
            _.each(widgets, function (wid) {
                if (wid.dataModelOptions.linkedParentWidget) {
                    // REFRESH HERE...
                }
            });
        }        
    }
    
})();
```

A snippet of `reportsContext'`service :

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('rage');

    app.service('reportsContext', ['$http', reportsContext]);

    function reportsContext($http) {

        this.encodeRageURL = function (sourceURL) {
            var encodedURL = sourceURL.replace(/ /g, "%20");
            encodedURL = encodedURL.replace(/</g, "%3C");
            encodedURL = encodedURL.replace(/>/g, "%3E");            
            return encodedURL;
        }

        // SAVE CHART DATA TO LOCAL CACHE
        this.saveChartCategoryAxisToLocalStorage = function (data) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("chartCategoryAxis", JSON.stringify(data));
        }

    }
})();
```

One other point is that in my main `directive` code, I can a `$broadcast` event which calls the WidgetLinking factory :
Notice how I'm passing in the `widgetLinkingFactory` in scope.$on. Is this a problem ?

```
// Called from my DataModel factory :
$rootScope.$broadcast('refreshLinkedWidgets', id, widgetLinkingFactory, dataModelOptions);

// Watcher setup in my directive code :
  scope.$on('refreshLinkedWidgets', function (event, parentWidgetId, widgetLinkingFactory, dataModelOptions) {
  widgetLinkingFactory.linkCharts(parentWidgetId, scope.widgets, dataModelOptions);
          });
```

I am wasting a lot of time with these injections, and it's driving me crazy.

Thanks ahead of time for your assistance.

regards,
Bob

Comment: Isn't your linking function outside of the app?

Comment: Do you understand what I've posted as an answer?  If you understand factories and this is some other issue, let me know.

Comment: Yes I understand 100%, thank you. I've been reading to try and figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I honestly don't use the syntax you are using, so I'm not 100%, but I think I see what you're trying to do and will take another look

Comment: Also, what is reportsContext?

Comment: @DaveM - but I'm willing to try your syntax. I picked up that syntax from John Papa tutorials.

Comment: You should use the syntax I'm using anyway because it will let you minify the code later and I think is more commonly used

Comment: I've added a snippet of reportsContext. thanks

Comment: `test-fact.js` in this plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/I6MJRx?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to read up on factories/services, but the following will work:

```
var app = angular.module('rage')
app.factory('hi', [function(){
  var service = {};
  service.sayHi = function(){return 'hi'}
  return service;
}];

app.factory('bye', [function(){
  var service = {};
  service.sayBye = function(){return 'bye'}
  return service;
}];

app.factory('combine', ['hi', 'bye', function(hi, bye){
  var service = {};
  service.sayHi = hi.sayHi;
  service.sayBye = bye.sayBye;
  return service;
}];
```

And in controller...

```
app.controller('test', ['combine', function(combine){
  console.log(combine.sayHi());
  console.log(combine.sayBye());
}];
```

Comment: your answer was extremely helpful, as I am making great progress now. I believe your syntax is more consistent, and certainly more widely used. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So it would be most helpful if you created a plunk or something where we could fork your code and test a fix.   Looking over your services it doen't seem that they are returning anything.   I typically set up all of my services using the "factory" method as shown below

```
 var app = angular.module('Bret.ApiM', ['ngRoute', 'angularFileUpload']);
app.factory('Bret.Api', ['$http', function ($http: ng.IHttpService) {
    var adminService = new Bret.Api($http);
    return adminService;
}]);
```

As you can see I give it a name and define what services it needs and then I create an object that is my service and return it to be consumed by something else.  The above syntax is TypeScript which plays very nice with Angular as that is what the Angular team uses.

Comment: I like the new TS syntax, and will start using it soon.